# Problema trampolin en Unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

Hace poco que empece a programar en Unity así que soy bastante novato en lo que se refiere a esto. Eh estado intentando hacer una especie de "trampolín" o resorte en un proyecto 2D. Lo intente hacer con los componentes Spring2D pero todavía no encontré manera de hacerlo con esto, por lo que intente lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice fue crear un GameObject con un RigidBody 2D y Gravity Scale=0, y cree el siguiente script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class resorte : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 posicionInicial;
    private Vector2 vectorVersorDirector;
    private bool retornarPosicion = false;
    private Rigidbody2D my_rgb2;
    public float velocidadRestitucion;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        my_rgb2 = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        posicionInicial = gameObject.transform.position;
        vectorVersorDirector = new Vector2();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        vectorVersorDirector.x = posicionInicial.x - gameObject.transform.position.x;
        vectorVersorDirector.y = posicionInicial.y - gameObject.transform.position.y;
        vectorVersorDirector.Normalize();
        if (retornarPosicion)
        {
            my_rgb2.velocity = vectorVersorDirector * velocidadRestitucion;
        }

        if (posicionInicial.y < gameObject.transform.position.y)
        {
            my_rgb2.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            gameObject.transform.position = posicionInicial;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            retornarPosicion = true;
    }
}
```

Lo que hago es dejar que la plataforma se mueva hasta que se encuentre con el suelo, que lleva el tag "Ground". Entonces, le doy velocidad en dirección al punto inicial (el cual lo guardo al comienzo del script) y cuando su posición es mayor al de la posición inicial, que se corrija y vuelva a la posición inicial.

El tema es que solo funciona una sola vez, porque luego ocurre lo siguiente:

https://gyazo.com/3eb3749e2540bc550bb86e99d8167b4d

No se si le estoy pifiando con la logica o si estoy ignorando algun comportamiento de Unity que se me esta escapando. Cualquier ayuda que puedan aportarme, se los voy a agradecer mucho.

Saludos

Comment: y si intentas poner después de `gameObject.transform.position = posicionInicial; ` algo como ` retornarPosicion = true;` para que pueda entrar al primer if?

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar el update (que de hecho deberías usar el FixedUpdate para las físicas) usas un addForce cuando colisione con un trampolín?

```
collision.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, springForce));
```

Y ahí le das el springForce que prefieras.

Answer (score 0):

Corrijo ligeramente lo que comenta @Sebastian Paduano, ya que si aplicas la fuerza así la estarás aplicando en Newtons, y en tu caso necesitas que se aplique como una energía de impulso, así la energía que reciba lo hará subir siempre lo mismo sin sorpresas, sería más correcto así

```
collision.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, springForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Y en el FixedUpdate() siempre para aplicar fuerzas a rigidbodies.